# Using cursor as a return variable

Tags: python, oracle, python-3.x, cursor

I am running a query against Oracle 11g that I've written in Python 3.6:

```
# running CP_ALL_PCK.get_pr

# open conncetion
con_get_pr = cx_Oracle.connect("****", "****", "****")
pr_cursor = con_get_pr.cursor()

# set parameters
pCurs = pr_cursor.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)
pRetCode = pr_cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)

# run cursor
try:
  pr_cursor.callproc('CP_ALL_PCK.get_pr',(pCurs,pRetCode))
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as exception:
  print ('Failed to call procedure')
  print (exception)
  exit (1)

pr_cursor.fetchall()

res = pCurs.fetchall()
for row in res:
    print(row)

pr_cursor.close()
con.close()
```

and I'm getting this error when I try to use the pCurs cursor:

```
pr_cursor.fetchall()
cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: not a query
```

How do I use and iterate through this cursor? i searched for an answer in the documentation of cx_oracle but couldn't find any reference of iterating through a cursor returned as a variable from procedure.

Comment: You say *"this error"* but you don't tell us what the error is. It's pretty hard to tell you what's wrong without that vital clue.

Comment: Remove the line `pr_cursor.fetchall()` as the error says it is not a query

Comment: @Plirkee, but how do i itirate through pCurs? am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @neoghost for `pCurs` you got the line `res = pCurs.fetchall()`, as opposed to `pr_cursor` that has nothing to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it!

```
# run cursor
try:
  res = pr_cursor.callproc('<name of procedure>',[pCurs,pRetCode])[0]
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as exception:
  print ('Failed to call procedure')
  print (exception)
  exit (1)

i=0
for line in res:
    i=i+1
    print ("{}) {}".format(i,line))

pr_cursor.close()
con.close()
```

i was missing the [0] at the end to indicate that i want the cursor returned.
thanks everyone for helping.

found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523811/return-a-stored-procedure-out-cursor-variable-in-cx-oracle?rq=1)